# How to read line from a text file as a string in matlab?

Tags: matlab, file-io

I am trying to read a text file in MATLAB which has a format like the following. I am looking to read the whole line as a string.

```
 2402:0.099061 2404:0.136546 2406:0.447161 2407:0.126333 2408:0.213803 2411:0.068189
```

I tried couple of things.

`textscan(fid, '%s')` reads the line but splits the line into cells at spaces.

`fscanf(fid, '%s')` reads the line as a string but removes all the spaces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`fgetl(fid)` will do what you're looking for.  Newline is stripped off.

Answer (score 2):

`textscan` uses a whitespace delimeter by default. Set the delimiter to an empty string:

```
>> q = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter', '');
>> q{1}{:}
ans = 2402:0.099061 2404:0.136546 2406:0.447161 2407:0.126333 2408:0.213803 2411:0.068189
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read the *whole file* as string (your file has only one line), try:

```
s = fileread('input.txt');   %# returns a char vector
s = strtrim(s);              %# trim whitespaces
```

If you look at the source code of FILEREAD function, it is basically reading the file in binary mode as an array of characters: `fread(fid, '*char')`

Answer (score 0):

whitespace is treated as a delimiter by default with textscan.
specify a different delimiter (that is not present in your data) when calling, that should do the trick, add this f.e.

```
    'delimiter', '|'
```

you can also use

```
    file = textread(<fileref goes here>, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n')
```

then

```
    file{1,1}
```

will return

```
    ans =

    2402:0.099061 2404:0.136546 2406:0.447161 2407:0.126333 2408:0.213803 2411:0.068189
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
clc;
fid = fopen('fileName.m');

while ischar(tline)
    disp(strcat("Line imported: ",tline))
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end

fclose(fid);
```